# Can I have a listing with fixed column code and full-flexible comments?

Tags: listings

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
int a; // a number
int b; // another number
// ...
int sum = add(a, b); // their sum
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible]
int a; // a number
int b; // another number
// ...
int sum = add(a, b); // their sum
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to sort of merge these two styles:

- `fixed` column alignment for code (or anything *not* a comment)
- `fullflexible` column alignment for comments

Comment: What about not using `fixed` altogether? The monospaced font for the code part already ensures column alignment; expanding the interletter space just makes for difficult reading.

Comment: @egreg I'm not guaranteed the author will want to use monospace code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that it's possible, adding `\lst@column@fullflexible` to the `commentstyle`.

So, with

```
\makeatletter
\let\commentfullflexible\lst@column@fullflexible
\makeatother
```

define your `\lstset` as

```
\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily\commentfullflexible
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\makeatletter
\let\commentfullflexible\lst@column@fullflexible
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily
}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Normal comments}]
int a; // a number
int b; // another number
// ...
int sum = add(a, b); // their sum
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\rmfamily\commentfullflexible
}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Fullflexible comments}]
int a; // a number
int b; // another number
// ...
int sum = add(a, b); // their sum
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question, but I do personally wonder if there's a way to keep the `//` teletype – but that's not in the scope of this question :) But for those who might want this, I would define `\commentfullflexible` to perhaps somehow parse the `// comment` with a low-level `\def` (or `expl3` equivalent), setting the `//` in `basicstyle`.  If I come up with a good answer, I'll ask a separate Q and self-answer (unless anyone else is curious enough to beat me to the punch).